# How to use tensorflow's ncf model to predict?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, recommendation-engine, tensorflow-model-garden

Hi I'm new to tensorflow and neural networks. Trying to understand the [ncf recommendation model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/recommendation) in tensorflow's official models repo.

My understanding is that you build a model with input layers and learning layers. Then you create batches of data to train the model, and then you use test data to evaluate the model. This is done in this [file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/recommendation/ncf_keras_main.py).

However, I'm having trouble to understand the input layers.

It shows in the code

```
user_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(
      shape=(1,), name=movielens.USER_COLUMN, dtype=tf.int32)
```

Which to my understanding you can input one parameter at a time.

However I'm only able to use the following dummy data to call predict_on_batch

```
user_input = np.full(shape=(256,),fill_value=1, dtype=np.int32)
item_input = np.full(shape=(256,),fill_value=1, dtype=np.int32)
valid_pt_mask_input = np.full(shape=(256,),fill_value=True, dtype=np.bool)
dup_mask_input = np.full(shape=(256,),fill_value=1, dtype=np.int32)
label_input = np.full(shape=(256,),fill_value=True, dtype=np.bool)
test_input_list = [user_input,item_input,valid_pt_mask_input,dup_mask_input,label_input]

tf.print(keras_model.predict_on_batch(test_input_list))
```

When I run the following code:

```
    user_input = np.full(shape=(1,),fill_value=1, dtype=np.int32)
    item_input = np.full(shape=(1,),fill_value=1, dtype=np.int32)
    valid_pt_mask_input = np.full(shape=(1,),fill_value=True, dtype=np.bool)
    dup_mask_input = np.full(shape=(1,),fill_value=1, dtype=np.int32)
    label_input = np.full(shape=(1,),fill_value=True, dtype=np.bool)
    test_input_list = [user_input,item_input,valid_pt_mask_input,dup_mask_input,label_input]

    classes = _model.predict(test_input_list)
    tf.print(classes)
```

I got this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 1 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 256
     [[{{node model_1/metric_layer/StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/Reshape_1}}]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_2828]
```

Can somebody help me with how to use this model to predict with single inputs? 
And also why is item_id required with user_id when making the prediction? Shouldn't it be you provide a list of users the model returns a list of items?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how to make predictions on their model as well. I'd be greatly interested in your conclusions if/when you have one.

Comment: Honestly the code is poorly implemented I think. I find it very convoluted for no reason.

Comment: Hi @aaaaahaaaaa I ended up using `keras_model.predict_on_batch(test_input_list)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to TensorFlow and deep learning, this recommendations project is probably not a good place to start. The code is not documented and the architecture might be a confusing to follow along.

Anyway, to answer your questions, the model does not take single inputs to make predictions. Looking at the code, there are 5 inputs (user_id, item_id, duplicate_mask, valid_pt_mask, label) but this is really meant for training. If you just want to make predictions, you actually only need the user_id and item_id. This model is making predictions based on user_id and item_id interactions and this is why you need both. However, you can't directly do that unless you cut the unnecessary parts of the model off when making predictions. Below is the code on how to do that after your model object called `keras_model` is trained (I used tf-model-official version 2.5.0 and it worked fine):

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import tensorflow as tf

inputUserIds = keras_model.input['user_id']
inputItemIds = keras_model.input['item_id']
# Cut off the unnecessary parts of the model for predictions.
# Specifically, we're removing the loss and metric layers in the architecture.
# Note: we are not training a new model, just taking the parts of the model we need.
outputs = keras_model.get_layer('rating').output
newModel = Model(inputs=[inputUserIds, inputItemIds], outputs=outputs)

## Make predictions for user 1 with items ids 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
# Make a user. Each row will be user_id 1. The shape of this tensor is (5,1)
userIds = tf.constant([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])[:, tf.newaxis]
# Make a tensor of items. Each row will be different item ids. The shape of this tensor is (5,1)
itemIds = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5])[:, tf.newaxis]

# Make preds. This predicts for user id 1 and items ids 1,2,3,4,5.
preds = newModel.predict(x=[userIds, itemIds])
```

So, if you make predictions, you want to create all item-user combinations and then sort the predictions in descending order, while keeping track of the indices, for each user. The top item for that user will be the models prediction for most likely to be interacted with for that user, the 2nd item will be models predictions for 2nd most likely to be interacted with, and so forth.

There is a folder called "summaries" which gets created when running this ncf_keras_main.py file. If you point tensorboard at that folder, you can explore the model architecture under the graphs tab on the top left. It might help understand the code a little bit better. To run tensorboard, you open a terminal and type

```
tensorboard --logdir location_of_summaries_folder_here
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the ncf model before but it looks like you are inputting the training data as 1 sample with 256 features instead of 256 samples, each with 1 feature. Just flip your numpy arrays around, make sure the feature matrices are 2D, and that the number of features is the first dimension.

```
user_input = np.full(shape=(1,256),fill_value=1, dtype=np.int32)
```

...etc for the others. (well, the labels should stay 1D as you have them)

Similarly make sure in your prediction inputs that the feature matrix is 2D:

```
user_input = np.full(shape=(1,1),fill_value=1, dtype=np.int32)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
I tried both of your suggestions, still getting errors, this time for both.

Comment: The above was not a complete solution but a suggestion of how to proceed. I expect you'll have to make modifications to several of your input matrices.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep trying to modify.